# How to make a connection between between a form and database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I  want to make a connection between a hypothetical form and database (not localhost).

I do not get an error. However, data are not inserted in the database. I try to use the following codes, but not sure where is the issue. Please consider I am very new to PHP and it is very like that I have missed somethings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="new.php">
A : <input type="text" name="X1" placeholder="Enter A" /><br />
B : <input type="text" name="X2" placeholder="Enter B" /><br />
C : <input type="text" name="Y1" placeholder="Enter C" /><br />
D : <input type="text" name="Y2" placeholder="Enter D" /><br />
<br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $dbhost = "db1109865_hf";
    $X1 = "dbX1";
    $X2 = "dbX2";
 $Y1 = "dbY1";
    $Y2 = "dbY2";
    $dbname = "abc";

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $X1, $X2,$Y1,$Y2, $dbname) or die('Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

Comment: mysql_connect is outdated and deprecated so try to use modern techniqies like pdo https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: what is the equivalent to mysql_connect

Comment: mysqli_connect https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysqli-connect.php  or pdo connect https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.connections.php  but essentially you have to rewrite it and check also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: add you new text and enable error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display   to see if your code produces error.

Comment: you complete code is not good. First you php code runs evertime, so you check if the page was submitted. you shoukld strat at the begining with a tutoial or two. btw. 500 means that it can't find your webpage, as i don't know what cpde and you have done

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect, but it shows you how it is done.
mysli connct has only 4 parametrs.
As seen in the example.

Of course it will only open, when all paramerts databasename, hostname muserna, and password are correct.

You must especially during explorig and developing [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). 
So that you can check and eliminate errors that occir.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="new.php">
A : <input type="text" name="X1" placeholder="Enter username" /><br />
B : <input type="text" name="X2" placeholder="Enter password" /><br />
C : <input type="text" name="Y1" placeholder="Enter C" /><br />
D : <input type="text" name="Y2" placeholder="Enter D" /><br />
<br></br>
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){


    $dbhost = "db1109865_hf";
    $dbname = "abc";
    $username = $_POST['X1']; 
    $password = $_POST['X1'];

 $Y1 = = $_POST['Y1'];
    $Y2 = = $_POST['Y2'];
    $link= new mysqli($dbhostT, $username, $password, $dbname;
    if (!$link) {
        echo "error connecting." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debug-errrorummer: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debug-error message: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
    echo "connected";
}
?>
```

Comment: To login into a database you need a username like root and a password. like you use it in mysql workbench or phpomyadmin or the command prompt  mysql -u username -p password

Comment: You have to be more explicit  and i doubrt that it says that

Comment: they must be replaced by $username and $password see code now

Comment: yes, when all the paramerts are correct give it a try

Comment: Thank you for your help